# How do I bundle one page in nextJS with a manual webpack config?

Tags: express, webpack, next.js

I'm using webpack on the server and want to bundle only one page that is compiled with nextJS.

Right now, the directory structure consists of several pages like:

```
app
about
contact
```

Is there any way to compile just the app directory, that is, compiled with NextJS? I'm using express to run the app and have access to the paths I need for the page

Comment: what do you mean by bundle? doesn't nextjs bundle it for you?